# Query all instances of a model with 0 associations

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a `Model1`and a `Model2` with an 1:N relationship (Model1 has_many Model2). How can I query all the instances of `Model1` without any association with any `Model2`?

Comment: you want to fetch those objects of model 1 who dont have any assosiation present in model 2.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
@model2_ids = Model2.pluck(:model1_id)
@some_variable = Model1.where.not(id: @model2_ids)
```

Comment: That won't work very well for bigger tables. You first get all ids from one table and then put them back into another query. The suggestion by @Athar is the better approach, because the Database can handle the hard work.

Answer (score 0):

considering table name of Model1 is `model1` and table name of Model2 is `model2`

try this

```
Model1.joins("left outer join model2 on model2.model1_id = model1.id").where(model2: {model1_id: nil})
```